# Read data from Hadoop HDFS with SparkSQL connector to visualize it in Superset?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

on a Ubuntu server I set up Divolte Collector to gather clickstream data from websites. The data is being stored in Hadoop HDFS (Avro files).
(http://divolte.io/)

Then I would like to visualize the data with Airbnb Superset which has several connectors to common databases (thanks to SqlAlchemy) but not to HDFS.

Superset has in particular a connector to SparkSQL thanks to JDBC Hive (http://airbnb.io/superset/installation.html#database-dependencies)

So is it possible to use it to retrieve HDFS clickstream data? Thanks

Comment: If you are asking if spark sql can connect to HDFS . Then the answer is yes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to read HDFS data in SparkSQL there are two major ways depening on your setup:

1. Read the table as it was defined in Hive (reading from a remote metastore) (probably not your case)
2. SparkSQL by default (if not configured otherwise) creates a [embedded metastore for Hive](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html) which allows you to issue DDL and DML statements using Hive syntax.
   You need an [external package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) for that to work `com.databricks:spark-avro`.

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE divolte_data
   USING com.databricks.spark.avro
   OPTIONS (path "path/to/divolte/avro");
   ```

Now data should be available inside the table `divolte_data`

Comment: Thanks for your answer